# rails error: relation already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to move my rails app into a docker container for production and I'm up to the last step of loading the production dump into the container.

I've done a backup of my current production database

```
pg_dump pdfcat_production > ~/pdfcat-20170728.dump
```

I've loaded this once before and it worked, it's the second time which is failing;

```
docker-compose run -e 'RAILS_ENV=production' app rake db:drop
docker-compose run -e 'RAILS_ENV=production' app rake db:create
cat ~/pdfcat-20170727.dump | docker exec -i 79766cf70617 psql -Upostgres
```

I get this error;

```
ERROR:  relation "categories" already exists
ERROR:  role "pdfcat" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "categories_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  role "pdfcat" does not exist
ALTER SEQUENCE
ERROR:  relation "clients" already exists
ERROR:  role "pdfcat" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "clients_id_seq" already exists
ERROR:  role "pdfcat" does not exist
```

After it finishes with all these errors I cannot load the web app.

Comment: Did you know that data persists in containers? If you remove the container and then load it, it should not give error. However, you may include this loading process in your dockerfile so that the data is loaded in the image and you are ready to use the image

Comment: If I try and remove the postgres container I get the Error response from daemon: driver "aufs" failed to remove root filesystem for 79766cf7061767655837750e72a0d12046081b5946562b67b576e0c6abfbc023: rename /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/178acb7c7bb25ef51b5c993bfd66f9e8689abe8e372808643a909aef326b2c4b /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/178acb7c7bb25ef51b5c993bfd66f9e8689abe8e372808643a909aef326b2c4b-removing: device or resource busy

Comment: How are you removing it? `docker rm <container_id>` ?

Comment: `docker container rm 79766cf70617` I've also just tried `docker rm 79766cf70617`

Comment: Try stopping it `docker stop 79766cf70617`

Comment: Still the same issue when I try to remove after stopping.

Comment: I think the file system it is trying to remove is also in use by some other container. System restart seems to be failproof solution for all such errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150360/discussion-between-map7-and-ayushya).

Answer (score 0):

The loading of  second time is giving errors because the data is already loaded into the containers and thus is not getting recreated. You need not load the data this time.

As for current situation, you can remove the containers and begin afresh and this time data loading will not give any errors. To remove container, you can use `docker rm <contianer_id>` and if there are problems while stopping or removing container then there is system restart which is failproof and stops all container. Restarting docker service may also be one option.

If you want to prepare a image which can load data first time for any system, you can include this data loading process inside the dockerfile.

Comment: I cannot reboot this system, is there another way?